# How to call any class function on click of android widget button?

Tags: android, widget

I have defined an App Widget (`AppWidgetProvider`, etc.), and I want to write an ad hoc program for the `onClick` of one of the buttons in the App Widget. The documentation describes how to inflate a layout for the App Widget and how to set a particular action on a button (see `RemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent()`), but I don't see a way to write an ad hoc `OnClickListener`() for the button in the way that we do for buttons in Activities.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. OnClickListener is just a method; you can call any code from within it.

Comment: @Paddy Foran : thanks for ur comment.  I am talking about Android Widget Button, like normal Activity button how can i get clickListener here for Widget button to perform some functionality . pls check my edit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. App Widgets are lightweight -- Android does not want App Widgets to run ad hoc code because that code could slow down the App Widget framework. Instead, AppWidgetProviders are supposed to do the work of App Widgets. The communication between AppWidgetProvider and AppWidget is a) the provider can update the widget with a new layout and b) the elements of that layout can send intents, which the AppWidgetProvider or other Android components can intercept and process.

See [Adding behavior to individual items](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#behavior) for an example of the AppWidgetProvider defining a custom Intent that it intercepts from its App Widget.

@Shubh: I edited your original question to make it clearer -- if you like the edit, you'll need to permit the edit so that others can see it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to call method from another class then make that method static and if not then elaborate your question.

And if you are asking for how to set the OnClicklistener over widget then try this:

```
     Yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v) {
         }
     };
```

Comment: @vinnetska : thanks, i am talking here for Android Widget button , pls chck my last edit.